# WordPress featured image does not display under custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Featured image does not display under custom post type. I have added theme support for thumbnails to the functions.php file and featured image is displayed under regular posts. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I think this is theme dependent.

Comment: Could you show how you've added theme support in functions.php? There could be a mistake there but we wouldn't be able to help w that without some code to look at. Also, what do you mean that it does not display? Are you saying it doesn't show in the post admin, or it is not showing up on your posts/pages?